# Create bunch popover bootstrap 5 with different content that contain on external file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-5, popover

how to load popover content from external file?

I have the index like this:

**index.html**

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-content-id="content1"></a>
<a tabindex="0" class="btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-content-id="content2"></a>

<!--more popover like this below-->
```

And the file that contain it's content:

**content.html**

```
<div>
  <div id="content1">
     <p>description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content2">
     <img src="item-image.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

I was thinking about using AJAX, but I'm barely know about it. so, how to load the content to the popover? and make it more dynamic because it will have bunch popover and it's content

(I'm using bootstrap 5.3, Just in case needed)

Note: I'm make sure this question is not duplicated

Comment: You're on the right track, you can use AJAX for this. You can use `XMLHttpRequest` or the more modern alternative: `fetch`. If what you use is limited to HTML, CSS and JS, using async JavaScript is your only option.